# self.add_widget inside function is not working

Tags: python, kivy

So i got the problem that `self.add_widget` is not working like it should. I know that the function is getting executed because of the print function and i create all the buttons and labels i want to. But somehow the self.add_widget method does not work. I have also tried it with .ids but i couldn't get it to work... The bn Button before the for loop also doesn't work. If you need more of my code just write me a message. Thank you!

.py:

```
class TrainingApp(MDApp):

def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name="mainwindow"))
    sm.add_widget(TrainingPlans(name="trainingplans"))
    sm.add_widget(SingleTrainingPlan(name="singletrainingplan"))
    sm.add_widget(FavouriteTrainings(name="favouritetrainings"))
    sm.add_widget(NavigationDrawer(name="navigationdrawer"))
    sm.add_widget(CurrentStats(name="currentstats"))

    self.favouritetrainings = FavouriteTrainings()
    self.fav_training_content = FavouriteTrainingsContent()

    return sm

class FavouriteTrainingsContent(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FavouriteTrainingsContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def refresh(self):
        print("i am in favourite trainings refresh")
        print("Favorite Plans:", main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans)

        bn = Button(text="Hello")

        self.add_widget(bn)
        for plan in main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans:
            print(plan)
            lbl = Label(
                size_hint=(.7, 1),
                text="Training " + str(plan)
            )

            btn = Button(
                size_hint=(.3, 1),
                background_normal="training_programs/Unknown-" + str(plan) + ".jpeg"
            )

            self.add_widget(lbl)
            self.add_widget(btn)
```

.kv:

```
<FavouriteTrainingsContent>
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    cols: 2
    height: self.minimum_height
    row_default_height: 150
    row_force_default: True


<FavouriteTrainings>
    name: "favouritetrainings"

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .85
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        FavouriteTrainingsContent:
            id: fav_tr_content
            width: root.width
            cols: 2

            Button:
                text: "hello"
```

nav drawer:

```
<ContentNavDrawer>
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Home"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "mainwindow"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Trainingplans"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "trainingplans"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Favourites"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "favouritetrainings"
                    app.do_cool_stuff()
                    app.fav_training_content.refresh()
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Recent Trainings"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "recenttrainings"
                    app.root.get_screen("recenttrainings").update()
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Settings"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "trainingplans"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `refresh()` method?

Comment: @JohnAnderson In my nav drawer on a button. I just updated the Post.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build()` method you are creating an instance of `FavouriteTrainingsContent` in the line:

```
self.fav_training_content = FavouriteTrainingsContent()
```

Then in your `kv` the line:

```
app.fav_training_content.refresh()
```

is calling the `refresh()` method of that instance. However, that instance is not the instance that is in your GUI. The `FavouriteTrainingsContent` instance in your GUI is created by the line:

```
sm.add_widget(FavouriteTrainings(name="favouritetrainings"))
```

in conjunction with the `kv` rule:

```
<FavouriteTrainings>
    name: "favouritetrainings"

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .85
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        FavouriteTrainingsContent:
            id: fav_tr_content
            width: root.width
            cols: 2

            Button:
                text: "hello"
```

So, you must access the correct instance of `FavouriteTrainingsContent`. One way is to access it through the `ScreenManager` and `ids`:

```
app.root.get_screen('favouritetrainings').ids.fav_tr_content.refresh()
```

Another way is to correctly assign the value of `fav_training_content` in the build method, like this:

```
def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name="mainwindow"))
    sm.add_widget(TrainingPlans(name="trainingplans"))
    sm.add_widget(SingleTrainingPlan(name="singletrainingplan"))
    self.favouritetrainings = FavouriteTrainings(name="favouritetrainings")  # save reference to instance of FavouriteTrainings 
    sm.add_widget(self.FavouriteTrainings)
    sm.add_widget(NavigationDrawer(name="navigationdrawer"))
    sm.add_widget(CurrentStats(name="currentstats"))

    self.fav_training_content = self.favouritetrainings.ids.fav_tr_content  # get correct instance of FavouriteTrainingsContent
    return sm
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out all the time. You are amazing!

Comment: It somehow still isn't working i just tried it. Do you know what the reason could be for this?

Comment: Nevermind it works with the first example. The second one doesn't work for me though. Thanks!